# How to avoid page numbering being re-started by titlepage?

Tags: titles, page-numbering

See the MWE below. How can I avoid that page numbering in the frontmatter is re-started by `\titlepage`? I would like the preface to have page number V.

---

```
\documentclass{book}  

\usepackage{lipsum}                  
\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}       
\usepackage{bookmark} 

\title{Lipsum}      
\author{lpdbw}                  

\begin{document} 

\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\lipsum                

\begin{titlepage}      
\maketitle             
\end{titlepage}        

\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

---

PS: Question edited and reformulated.

Comment: just put `\setcounter{4}` before `\chapter*{Preface}`.  (won't work if you have the preface in a separate file, and `\include{preface}` because of a built-in asynchronicity.  but `\clearpage` after the `\setcounter` should take care of that, with no blank pages as long as nothing is on the page.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution: Remove the lines with `\setcounter{page}` in the titlepage definition.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\makeatletter    
    \if@compatibility
\renewenvironment{titlepage}
    {%
      \cleardoublepage
      \if@twocolumn
        \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
      \else
        \@restonecolfalse\newpage
      \fi
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      %\setcounter{page}\z@
    }%
    {\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
    }
\else
\renewenvironment{titlepage}
    {%
      \cleardoublepage
      \if@twocolumn
        \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
      \else
        \@restonecolfalse\newpage
      \fi
      \thispagestyle{empty}%
      %\setcounter{page}\@ne
    }%
    {\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
     \if@twoside\else
       % \setcounter{page}\@ne
     \fi
    }
\fi
\makeatother

\title{Lipsum}
\author{lpdbw}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\lipsum

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{titlepage}

\chapter*{Preface}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, one can just do it without `titlepage`:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\title{Lipsum}
\author{lpdbw}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\lipsum

\cleardoublepage

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Preface}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: This can be done by `xpatch` easier.

Answer (score 8):

With `book.cls` you can't avoid at user level that the page numbering restarts at `titlepage`: `\setcounter{page}{1}` is hard wired. So you would have to redefine `titlepage` or reset the page counter after `\begin{titlepage}` manually.

In the KOMA class scrbook, the page counter is not reset by `titlepage` but  by `\maketitle`, and `\maketitle` has an optional argument to override the page counter. So you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\title{Lipsum Here page: \thepage}
\author{lpdbw}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}
abc          

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle[\value{page}]     
\end{titlepage}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't want to change the documentclass in an already finished document and hence I would rather stick to `book`. Is it possible to store the value of the counter of the last page before the titlepage? This would enable me to set the counter manually after the titlepage to this value.

Comment: ... and what's about chaning the behaviour of `titlepage`? It shouldn't be too diffcult to insert some lines in the preamble preventing `book` to restart page numbering at the titlepage ...

Comment: Sure, you can store the value in a counter. But imho the easiest is to set a concrete (odd!) number like this: `\begin{titlepage}\setcounter{page}{3}` – you can't have so many pages before titlepage. Btw: You should use the `[notitlepage]` in the book options. Without it `\maketitle` inserts a titlepage environment too, which will reset the numbering again and this makes it arkward to find the correct place to reset the numbering.

Comment: The problem with setting a concrete value is if I change something before the titlpage I migh forget to adjust that manually. I have changed the definition of `titlepage` now --> have put that in an answer (see below) since not enough space in comment. What's your opinion on that solution?

Comment: I added an answer for that suggestion, now. I think, it might help for some cases where one doesn't want to redefine `titlepage`.

Answer (score 2):

The `titlepage` environment restarts the page counter at `1`. Therefore you have two
pages with page number `I`, the very first page and the first title page.

`\pagenumbering{Alph}` would work, but the previous page is not yet finished and therefore also the previous page would be `A`. This is fixed by starting a new page explicitly:

```
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Alph}
```

Also the method with disabled page anchors work, page anchors can be disabled for some pages only, e.g.:

```
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\frontmatter
 ....
\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
```

Comment: Not sure whether there is a misunderstanding: How does your answer solve the problem of page numbering starting anew with the titlepage? I would like the preface (see edited question) to have page number V ...

Comment: @lpdbw: You edited your question quite a lot. Heiko is answering to the first version.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thought his answer was already referring to the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, without redefining the `titlepage` (based on the comments):

Set the page counter manually. We store the page counter in another counter, so it works dynamically, and we don't need to hardcode the page number.

```
\newcounter{titlepagenumber}
\setcounter{titlepagenumber}{\value{page}}
\begin{titlepage}
    \setcounter{page}{\thetitlepagenumber}
    
    % Test if it works:
    \thepage
\end{titlepage}
```